# "is not valid at this position, expecting FOR, LOCK..." help a mysql workbench beginner

Tags: mysql, runtime-error, mysql-workbench

i'm using SQL Workbench and it's been 3 days since i started learning SQL, today i tried to create a database with pokémons, their names, ids, genre, other stuff, but i can't proceed because it keeps telling me that "id" is not valid at its position

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD1OX.png)

I tried doing the same thing on an online SQL tester and it worked just fine, can someone help me?

(sorry if bad english, i'm not a native speaker)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The syntax is `create table tablename (column definitions);`. You have a `;` after `create table Pokemons`, then you have an extra `use Pokemons;` then the column definitions.

Comment: You don't say `use tablename`, you can only use a database.

Comment: 'an online SQL tester and it worked just fine' - which one as a matter of interest.

Comment: it was this one from w3schools, but just now i tried running the same thing again and it said there's a syntax error, i think i did it right on the sql tester, and wrong on the workbench, anyway, it worked just fine now, thank you guys <3
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more accurate way to create a table, based on your example, would be to use a format similar to the one provided below:

```
create database Pokedex;
use Pokedex;

create table Pokemons (
id int primary key,
name VARCHAR(255),
genre VARCHAR(255)
);
```